# Book where man communicates telepathically with a being

Tags: story-identification, books, telepathy

I am looking for the name and/or author of a story that goes something like this:

A writer(?) is visited by a being and they communicate telepathically. The being eventually asks if the man has questions and the man asks how we (humans) can get to the point, technologically, that this being is at. The being says that the man wouldn't understand if the being explained in the way it normally would but that it would explain in another way. The being goes on to explain using a tree as an example.

The story is at least 20-30 years old and the authors last name might be Fry(e).

Comment: Doesn't look to be [Frye](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=Frye&type=Name)

Comment: Any chance it was Contact, by Carl Sagan? I only vaguely remember the ending, but it may have had a conversation like this.

Comment: It is not Contact. At least I sm pretty sure it is not. It is the same sort of idea as far as the way the being communicates with the human. If, in Contact, the being uses a tree as an allegory for the  progression of technological advances, then I guess it is that one :)

Comment: Is it possibly Sphere by Michael Crichton? This reminds me of Norman's interaction with the Sphere.

Comment: Not that one either...

Comment: Vaguely reminisces the Clifford Simak's *Time is the simplest thing*... but not quite. Admittedly, read that one long, long time ago...